# How to set Windows 7 backtick usage

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Is there a windows 7 setting that governs the application of backticks?

I don't know if it is the case on US keyboard layouts (is it?), but on my EN-UK layout if I press the backtick key then a vowel key without first hitting the space bar I'll end up with an `è` instead of `` ` `` which is highly inconvenient when programming (which I do a lot more than type Gallic languages).

Is there a way of telling windows I always want to use the backtick key as a backtick and never as a grave applicator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to EN-US layout where backticks are backticks. We like it simple over here.

Alternatively, you could use something like SharpKeys or edit the registry directly to replace a less-used key (ScrollLock...) with the backtick.

Comment: Not really an option to switch layouts as that will muck up nearly every other symbol key-mapping on my board :\

Comment: Do you have multiple UK layouts available? Sometimes there are Default/Winkeys/International options.

Comment: Thanks @meatspace. Switched from `English (Ireland) - Irish` to `English (Ireland) - United Kingdom` which helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: 
I simply type the backtick twice (<kbd>`</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>) and then remove the second backtick using backspace (`) and then carry on typing (`ain't this grand`).

Comment: I usually type backtick and then space when I want a single backtick.